# How to combine two codes into one function?

Tags: c++

My code creates arrays, I need to implement deletions for it, but I don’t know how to do it beautifully and correctly.

main code

```
template<class T1>
auto auto_vector(T1&& _Size) {
    return new int64_t[_Size]{};
}
template <class T1, class... T2>
auto auto_vector(T1&& _Size, T2&&... _Last)
{
    auto result = new decltype(auto_vector(_Last...))[_Size];
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < _Size; ++i) {
        result[i] = auto_vector(_Last...);
    }
    return result;
}
```

this is the code that I want to combine with the first

```
template <class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>
void del_vector(T4& _Del, T1& _Size, T2& _Size2, T3& _Size3) {
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < _Size3; ++i) {
        for (ptrdiff_t k = 0; k < _Size2; ++k) {
            delete _Del[i][k];
        }
        delete _Del[i];
    }
    delete _Del;
}
int main()
{
    auto map1 = auto_vector(_Size, _Size2, _Size3);

    auto map2 = auto_vector(3, 4, 5, 7);

    del_vector(map1, _Size, _Size2, _Size3);

    return 0;
}
```

I do not like this option I would like something like that.

```
int main()
{
    auto_vector map1(_Size, _Size2, _Size3);

    del_vector map1(_Size, _Size2, _Size3);

    //or so

    auto_vector<_Size, _Size2, _Size3> map1;

    del_vector<_Size, _Size2, _Size3> map1;

    return 0;
}
```

the reason why I do this is because I cannot implement the same thing using just a vector
and I don’t understand why the vector does not work with dynamic arrays, the fact is that I do not know the exact data
`_Size, _Size2, _Size3 = ?` before compilation.

therefore I use `new` and all this I do only for his sake.

if it is useful to you to look at the data for tests

```
cout << " ---------TEST---------- " << endl;
    for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < _Size3; ++i) {
        for (ptrdiff_t k = 0; k < _Size2; ++k) {
            for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < _Size; ++j) {
                cout << map1[i][k][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << " ---------TEST---------- " << endl;
```

Comment: Don't use identifiers that start with an underscore and then an uppercase letter. These are reserved for the implementation (compiler, standard library, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `new` operations in the code. Also `del_vector` doesn't make any sense in your preferred version as any decent class will deallocate its data in the destructor (lest it has no ownership over it).

What you need is to make a class or a template class that wraps things up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<size_t index, size_t dim>
void ModifyArray(std::array<size_t,dim>& lcAarray){}

template<size_t index, size_t dim, typename... Args>
void ModifyArray(std::array<size_t, dim>& lcAarray, size_t arg, Args... args)
{
    lcAarray[index] = arg;
    ModifyArray<index+1>(lcAarray, args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Args)> MakeArray(Args... args)
{
    std::array<size_t, sizeof...(Args)> lclArray;
    ModifyArray<0>(lclArray, args...);
    return lclArray;
}

template< std::size_t dim > 
class myMultiArray;

template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t crDim>
class MyMultiArrayIterator
{
    public:
    MyMultiArrayIterator(myMultiArray<dim>* multiArray, size_t index):
        m_pMultiArray(multiArray),
        m_index(index)
    {}

    template<size_t newDim = crDim+1,  typename std::enable_if<newDim < dim, int>::type = 0>
    MyMultiArrayIterator<dim, newDim> operator [] (size_t idx)
    {
        return MyMultiArrayIterator<dim, newDim>(m_pMultiArray, m_index + idx*m_pMultiArray->GetStep(crDim));
    }

    template<size_t newDim = crDim+1,  typename std::enable_if<newDim == dim, int>::type = 0>
    int& operator [] (size_t idx)
    {
        return m_pMultiArray->GetValue(m_index+idx*m_pMultiArray->GetStep(crDim));
    }

    private:
    size_t              m_index;
    myMultiArray<dim>*  m_pMultiArray;
};

template< std::size_t dim > 
class myMultiArray
{
public:
    myMultiArray() = default;

    template<class... Args, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == dim-1, int>::type = 0>
    myMultiArray(size_t size0, Args... args)
    {
        m_sizes = MakeArray(size0, args...);

        std::size_t uTotalSize = 1;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            m_steps[i] = uTotalSize;
            uTotalSize *= m_sizes[i];
        }
        std::cout  << uTotalSize << "\n";
        m_data.resize(uTotalSize);
     }
     // resizes m_data to multiplication of sizes
     int operator  () (std::array < std::size_t, dim > indexes) const
     {
        return m_data[computeIndex(indexes)];
     }
     int &operator  () (std::array < std::size_t, dim > indexes)
     {
        return m_data[computeIndex(indexes)];
     }
     // modify operator
     // you'll probably need more utility functions for such a multi dimensional array

     int GetValue(size_t index) const
     {
        return m_data[index];
     }

     int &GetValue(size_t index)
     {
        return m_data[index];
     }

     size_t GetSize(size_t index) const
     {
         return m_sizes[index];
     }

     size_t GetStep(size_t index) const
     {
         return m_steps[index];
     }

     MyMultiArrayIterator<dim, 1> operator [] (size_t index)
     {
         return  MyMultiArrayIterator<dim, 1>(this, index*m_steps[0]);
     }

private:
     size_t computeIndex(std::array < std::size_t, dim > indexes)
     {
       size_t location = 0;
       for(size_t i=0; i< dim; i++)
       {
           location += m_steps[i]*indexes[i];
       }
       return location;
    }

private:
    std::vector < int >             m_data;
    std::array < std::size_t, dim > m_sizes;
    std::array < std::size_t, dim > m_steps;
};

template<typename... Args>
myMultiArray<sizeof...(Args)> MakeMyMultiArray(Args... args)
{
    return myMultiArray<sizeof...(Args)>(args...);
}

int main ()
{
    auto mapMA = MakeMyMultiArray(3,4,5);

    mapMA({2ull,3ull,4ull}) = 7;
    std::cout << mapMA({{2ull,3ull,4ull}})  << "\n";
    std::cout << mapMA[2][3][4];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `myMultiArray map1(_Size3, _Size2, _Size);`

how can I check this, it does not work, I do not understand a bit.
can write with an example `main` please

Comment: @1221 it will have to be `myMultiArray<3> map1({{_Size3, _Size2, _Size}});` due to `std::array` nuances and the fact that there is no class template type deduction in C++14.

Comment: `array<size_t, dim> m_sizes;`
hmm .. trying to understand why it gives an error.

Comment: but I also want to say that the implementation looks strange. :)

Comment: @1221 alright I wrote you a better example with an issue fixed;

Comment: @1221 there is a better way to write it - without `std::array` in the constructor but it will require SFINEA stuff - which is complicated.

Comment: I’ll try now to figure out how it works to understand. :)

Comment: and this code is better than mine, meaning it works faster yes?

Comment: @1221 indeed multitude of `new` makes allocation slower and might result in poor memory fragmentation. Also accessing data is faster because you won't need to dereference several pointers.

Comment: I can access the array like this, otherwise it gives me an error?
`map1[i][k][j]` 
or I can’t do this, it’s important for me what it would be.

Comment: @1221 you'll need to make an iterator class for this kind of access (so that `operator []` returns appropriate iterator). If it was two dimensional you could've simply returned a pointer.

Comment: I’ll deal with it again, but I like your code, it’s unusual, but I’m interested, can I remove the extra brackets `({{_Size3, _Size2, _Size}})`

Comment: @1221 it requires making a constructor that accepts `(args...)` simple implementation isn't too hard, but to make it type-safe you'll have to make restrictions to number of inputs and make sure they are integer-like types. To do so: check out type_traits STL library and SFINAE principles. Find some guides online - its syntax is annoying AF.

Comment: Yes, I don’t like it either, I don’t want to use SFINAE code to become very complex

Comment: @1221 also, if you can assume that you have only 3 dimension and third size is fixed - say 3 - then you can make a two dimensional dynamic array of elements `std::array<int,3>` - which much easier to implement than genetic multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I don’t have a fixed size; it can be 3 or maybe 10 or 2 so there’s no way to create a simple one :)

Comment: I removed two brackets and the code works, is this normal? :)
`({_Size3, _Size2, _Size})`

Comment: I’m kind of starting to understand how your code works. I would never have thought of that. Did you come up with this?

Comment: @1221 I remember there was some problem when initializing `std::array` and `std::vector` from initializer list - that sometimes it doesn't compile or work properly - which is why I added extra brackets. But if it works then it should be fine. Just be careful.

Comment: I can do this, otherwise I'm not sure what works?
`map1({ i, k, map1({ i, k, j }) });`

Comment: help me to add an implementation with brackets map1[4][5][2] otherwise I won’t be able to do it

Comment: @1221 I wrote something simple, but seriously you ought to write it yourself. Don't ask for more.

Comment: I didn’t even hope that you would write :)
Thank.